# Close the gap when I have a fixed width html

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div id="navigation" class="blueColor">
      <ul id="TopMenu">
            <li><a  href="../src/projects.aspx">Projects<span class="subDetails blueColor">ARCHITECTURAL PROJECTS SUCH AS BUILDINGS, MASTER PLANS ETC.</span></a></li>  
            <li><a  href="../src/media.aspx">Media<span class="subDetails blueColor">DRAWINGS, PHOTOS, FILMS, NEWSPAPER CLIPPINGS ETC. THAT EXPLAIN THE \"PROJECTS\" AND CAPTURE THEIR LARGER CULTURAL BACKGROUND</span></a></li>              
      </ul>
</div>
```

and this css style:

```
    #logo #navigation
    {
        float:left;
        width: 255px;
        font:35px Arial;
    }

    #logo #navigation li span.subDetails{
      float:left;
      font:10px Arial;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      padding-top:4px;
      width:140px;
      opacity: 0.2;
    }

    ul#TopMenu{
     position:absolute;
     margin-top:6px
    }
    #logo #navigation ul:first-child{
      margin-left:55px;
    }
    #logo #navigation li{
      margin-left:0px;
      width:167px;
      float:left;
    }
```

If you move the mouse over the 2 words Foo and Bar there is a small gap of 1px.
I want to close this gap, how can I do it?

Comment: add `white-space: nowrap;` to your li { ... } http://jsfiddle.net/ssxQc/

Comment: What type of gap you are talking about

Comment: May be you can put a screenshot here highlighting the GAP you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

`line-height: 110%;`

to the span CSS:

```
span { 
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white; 
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 110%;
}
li{
    width:20px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RWPNE/

Edit: We discovered the real HTML was different to the original question, and thus the solution was `margin-top: -1px;`

Comment: Yes, is correct but it still not working for my real page. I thought that this example would be the same. I updated my question.

Comment: I see - try using `margin-top: -1px;` on the span, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what do you want. But, if you don't mind about the paddings you can add a padding-top to the span, it consumes the space:

```
span { 
     width:100px;
     background:blue;
     font-size:30px;
     color:white; 
     text-align:center;
     padding-top:1px;
}

li{
    width:20px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. You have changed the example. It's a different case now :-(